# How to aggregate different log groups generated on Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-msk

I have created MSK cluster for event streaming and my producer and consumer lambda functions are producing different log groups on cloudwatch. I want to aggregate all the logs of producer and consumer lambda functions for debugging purpose in order to check the payloads and pub/sub flow.

What could be the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: You can try to use [CloudWatch Logs Insights to execute a log query across multiple log groups](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/07/cloudwatch-logs-insights-adds-cross-log-group-querying/).

CloudWatch Logs Insights enables you to interactively search and analyze your log data in Amazon CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: @TeddyAryono Can we get these insights of each log group on a single dashboard?